# Bib file without title using ieeetr, empty title

Tags: bibliographies, citing, bibliographystyle

**.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{document}

Lala\cite{aegerter2022biology}

\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\end{document}
```

**.bib**

```
@article{aegerter2022biology,
  author={Aegerter, Helena and Lambrecht, Bart N and Jakubzick, Claudia V},
  journal={Immunity},
  volume={55},
  pages={1564--1580},
  year={2022},
}
```

I am getting the following error: `empty title in aegerter2022biology` How could I get rid of it?

I know that `ieeetr` require title, but I do not want to show it on the bibliography chapter, thus I remove the `title` from the `.bib` file.

Comment: Instead of deleting fields in your `.bib` file you should use a style that suppresses the titles by design. This is a common style in chemistry, so perhaps one of the `biblatex-chem` styles would serve your purpose better.

Comment: Thanks. `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,articletitle=false]{biblatex}` Is working for me. There is no `title` "error"